# Arduino clone voltage regulator

Tags: arduino, voltage-regulator

I am sourcing some parts for an Arduino clone. My question is really simple and I am quite sure that I know the answer, but I wanted to clarify my suspicion. Can I swap out the [LM7805](http://www.produktinfo.conrad.com/datenblaetter/175000-199999/179205-da-01-en-IC_7805_TO_220.pdf) with this part ?? [78M05F](http://www.produktinfo.conrad.com/datenblaetter/150000-174999/156945-da-01-en-SPANNUNGSREGLER_KIA78M05F_KEC_SOT89.pdf)

Comment: 2nd link is broken.

Comment: 2nd link fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use that regulator. It is a 5 volt output linear regulator. You could check to see if the max output currents were similar, but for arduino applications, they do not draw much current.

Comment: The maximum output current is of limited relevance anyway, as the actual maximum may be much, much less depending on the input voltage and heat sinking.

Answer (score 1):

LM7805 has output voltage 5V and output current 1.5A 
And 78M05F has output voltage 5V and output current < 1A

If the load is connected to the LDO requires currents below 1A, you can replace it.

Comment: A linear voltage regulator is not a "power supply" but rather only one component thereof.  The supply rating is the least of what any of its components can handle; in your typical no heatsink except the PCB Arduino style design this is thermal, rather than what the chip itself could achieve in some more ideal installation.  Accessories designed to plug into an Arduino style board should not assume availability of supply current in the realm which would challenge this part's ultimate rating; if they need that, they should have their own supply inputs, **especially** stepper motors.

Answer (score 1):

If you are powering your clone using batteries, I'd recommend using a Low dropout regulator, depending on you current requirement choose any one below

1.[LM2940](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2940-n.pdf&ei=pr8yUoS0I8WHrgfkjYG4Dg&usg=AFQjCNHblQ_v-4Y3wOyUqFRhgt74BQs5Ww&sig2=Whx0cV6_YQCykjM7WrZiXA&bvm=bv.52164340,d.bmk) this can withstand 1A

2.[LM2937](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CC8QFjAB&url=http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2937.pdf&ei=2r8yUrqtJcGMrQfDk4CACA&usg=AFQjCNGgt5gCMOYLFWiWY7VgzbnkJ2e8Gg&sig2=ozLo5dcWf2Hwved-_p0fMg&bvm=bv.52164340,d.bmk) this can withstand 0.5A

3.[LT1118](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CC8QFjAB&url=http://www.linear.com/docs/1108&ei=6b8yUtjIPMWOrgeI3IDgCQ&usg=AFQjCNHQWtSMusMubZfnoHWL_UNDIBDVTg&sig2=t1P9Cy-YbUo-6sjeiCBfYQ&bvm=bv.52164340,d.bmk)-5 this can withstand 0.8A

You can also run it at 3v3

1.[LT1763](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAB&url=http://www.linear.com/docs/3903&ei=BMAyUuu7K8yprAex5YCwAg&usg=AFQjCNESyidVheJCt1J6A5Ausx5op9SJIA&sig2=dz7znbdXiANkOU6iCCb9Lw&bvm=bv.52164340,d.bmk) this can withstand 0.5A

2.[LTC3525](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CC8QFjAB&url=http://www.linear.com/docs/9338&ei=GMAyUun5AYeQrQfZv4H4Bw&usg=AFQjCNGLce-qe-ZkqMeKZ7bEW0t7X2R4IQ&sig2=5kXA4Cs8e3CxA5GAOC0J1g&bvm=bv.52164340,d.bmk) this can withstand 0.4A